# Converting String to Double Value From Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, location

I am trying to convert my string into a double value so that I can use it as a CLLocation coordinate. I am having trouble with the two let statements userLongitude and userLatitude. I am getting the error:

> "Type 'Any' has no subscript members".

I am new to programming and none of the other answers seem to work.

```
if let fullName = value["full name"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String,
    let userLongitude = (snapshot.value!["long"] as String)?.doubleValue, 
    let userLatitude = (snapshot.value!["lat"] as String)?.doubleValue
```

Comment: You left out the important code. [Edit] your question wth the code where `value` is declared and initialized.

Comment: please show the structure of your firebase db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast type Any to Swift dictionary type `[String: Any]`.

```
if let fullName = value["full name"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String,
    let snap = snapshot.value as? [String: Any],
    let userLongitude = Double(snap["long"] as! String),
    let userLatitude = Double(snap["lat"] as! String)
```